# Is my batch contaminated / infected?

Tags: fermentation, contamination

Me again with another question.  So there's not been much activity from my brew lately (no bubbling, only 3rd day in the fermenter).  I opened up to take the gravity and temperature (1022, 21C), so it hasn't  finished fermenting yet.  The picture below shows my beer (it's supposed to be a pale ale).  Is it infected?  It doesn't smell bad.

[image: Picture of my batch]

Comment: It looks delicious. Making me very thirsty...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks OK to me.  What you're seeing is a combination of CO2 coming out of solution, hop trub, and coagulated proteins.  Relax, don't worry, have a homebrew.

Comment: And close the lid before it does get infected. :P

Answer (score 1):

One more thing.  I am a fan of not opening the lid more often than necessary.  I don't take temperature and if I take gravity it is only at the very beginning and end.  Keep in mind that every time you open it up is a chance for contamination.  Most contamination will be benign which is why these little things so rarely cause problems, but once in a while you will get unlucky.